# how to attach file(any file) to sql command with OleDB, and how to read it from access DB

Tags: c#, oledb

this is the test code that I'm trying to add a local photo by address to my access db

the test table has two columns int id, object file

```
  [Theory]
        [InlineData("test", @"D:\download\up.png")]
        public void InsertImage(string table,string address)
        {
            string query = SQL_Queries.Insert(table, new List<object>() { 0, "@file" });
            //query = 'insert into test values(0,@file);'
            Assert.True(Access.Execute(query,address));
        }
```

this is the access execute code which returns true or false if succeed

```
       public static bool Execute(string command, string address)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(address);
        try
        {
            ConnectionState(true);
            OleCommand = new OleDbCommand(command, Connection);
            OleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", file);
            OleCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Error = err.Message;
            ConnectionState(false);
            return false;
        }
        ConnectionState(false);
        return true;
    }
```

gives me an error
`cannot perform that operation`

Comment: What do you want to store in that table? The full filename (path included) or just the file or the file content?

Comment: i want to save the file it self, i want to save in access db an image